# VBA PDF TO EXCEL "Can't find project or Library"

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure where to put the PDF on my computer, I need to file to be in a certain path but I am not sure how to do that or change that in this code I found online.

It gives me an error at the min point but I am not sure where in the code you can actually change the path or I am not sure where the path is to even put the pdf file

```
Option Explicit

'Constants used in API functions.
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const VK_RETURN = &HD
Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100

Private Sub OpenPDF(strPDFPath As String, strPageNumber As String, strZoomValue As String)

    'Opens a PDF file to a specific page and with a specific zoom
    'using Adobe Reader Or Adobe Professional.
    'API functions are used to specify the necessary windows
    'and send the page and zoom info to the Adobe window.

    'By Christos Samaras
    'http://www.myengineeringworld.net

    Dim strPDFName                  As String
    Dim lParent                     As Long
    Dim lFirstChildWindow           As Long
    Dim lSecondChildFirstWindow     As Long
    Dim lSecondChildSecondWindow    As Long
    Dim dtStartTime               As Date

    'Check if the PDF path is correct.
    If FileExists(strPDFPath) = False Then
        MsgBox "The PDF path is incorect!", vbCritical, "Wrong path"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Get the PDF file name from the full path.
    On Error Resume Next
    strPDFName = Mid(strPDFPath, InStrRev(strPDFPath, "\") + 1, Len(strPDFPath))
    On Error GoTo 0

    'The following line depends on the apllication you are using.
    'For Word:
    'ThisDocument.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'For Power Point:
    'ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'Note that both Word & Power Point pop up a security window asking
    'for access to the specified PDf file.
    'For Access:
    'Application.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'For Excel:
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'Find the handle of the main/parent window.
    dtStartTime = Now()
    Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        lParent = 0
        DoEvents
        'For Adobe Reader.
        lParent = FindWindow("AcrobatSDIWindow", strPDFName & " - Adobe Reader")
        'For Adobe Professional.
        'lParent = FindWindow("AcrobatSDIWindow", strPDFName & " - Adobe Acrobat Pro")
        If lParent <> 0 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    If lParent <> 0 Then

        'Bring parent window to the foreground (above other windows).
        SetForegroundWindow (lParent)

        'Find the handle of the first child window.
        dtStartTime = Now()
        Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
            lFirstChildWindow = 0
            DoEvents
            lFirstChildWindow = FindWindowEx(lParent, ByVal 0&, vbNullString, "AVUICommandWidget")
            If lFirstChildWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        'Find the handles of the two subsequent windows.
        If lFirstChildWindow <> 0 Then
            dtStartTime = Now()
            Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
                lSecondChildFirstWindow = 0
                DoEvents
                lSecondChildFirstWindow = FindWindowEx(lFirstChildWindow, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
                If lSecondChildFirstWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
            Loop

            If lSecondChildFirstWindow <> 0 Then

                'Send the zoom value to the corresponding window.
                SendMessage lSecondChildFirstWindow, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal strZoomValue
                PostMessage lSecondChildFirstWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0

                dtStartTime = Now()
                Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
                    lSecondChildSecondWindow = 0
                    DoEvents
                    'Notice the difference in syntax between lSecondChildSecondWindow and lSecondChildFirstWindow.
                    'lSecondChildSecondWindow is the handle of the next child window after lSecondChildFirstWindow,
                    'while both windows have as parent window the lFirstChildWindow.
                    lSecondChildSecondWindow = FindWindowEx(lFirstChildWindow, lSecondChildFirstWindow, "Edit", vbNullString)
                    If lSecondChildSecondWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
                Loop
                If lSecondChildSecondWindow <> 0 Then

                    'Send the page number to the corresponding window.
                    SendMessage lSecondChildSecondWindow, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal strPageNumber
                    PostMessage lSecondChildSecondWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0

                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Function FileExists(strFilePath As String) As Boolean

    'Checks if a file exists.

    'By Christos Samaras
    'http://www.myengineeringworld.net

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Dir(strFilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub TestPDF()

    OpenPDF ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Sample File.pdf", 6, 143

End Sub
```

Comment: *error at the min point* - what is the *min point*? Also you need to pass the `FileName` to the path ... `OpenPDF ("C:\MyPDF.pdf","2","100")`

Comment: where have you declared the APIs?

Comment: i didn't include them but they are right above them:

Comment: 'Constants used in API functions.
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const VK_RETURN = &HD
Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100

Comment: I did pass the file name "ThisWorkbook.path

Comment: The place you copied the code from : http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/04/open-pdf-file-with-vba.html has got flawless code. Just copy starting from Option Explicit to End sub. Just one suggestion though, If you have no idea what's going on here, how wise is it to just copy and paste code.?

Comment: I am trying to understand some of it, but what do put with the min function, because I keep getting an error with it. I did copy it from beginning to end to.

Comment: as @ScottHoltzman asked, where is the min in code?

Comment: @RyanLehman: `ThisWorkbook.Path` is not a file name. It's a directory path, unless you added the PDF file name as well. And do you have all the API Functions as well, Like `FindWindow`? Also, are you trying to **Open** a PDF or save a PDF?

Comment: I thought I don't have to change anything with the min because I have this line strPDFName = Mid(strPDFPath, InStrRev(strPDFPath, "\") + 1, Len(strPDFPath))

Comment: is there something I need to add to that line ?

Comment: You need to make sure that `strPDFPath` is a full file name path, like `C:\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyPDF.pdf` ... The `Mid` code you are referencing pulls out just the file name - `MyPDF.pdf` in my example - so `FindWindow` can then look for it in the open windows.

Comment: so at where can I make it a path, as in which part ?

Comment: I am not sure how to make the text I have into a path

Comment: you are persistent. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a PDF file called abc.pdf in directory C:\Temp

Scroll down to the bottom of the code you will find a sub called `Test'

make sure the code looks like this

```
Sub TestPDF()

    OpenPDF "C:\Temp" & "\" & "abc.pdf", 1, 100

End Sub
```

Comment: I did exactly that and it says Compile error: Can't find project or library

Comment: add VBA in front of MID, `VBA.Mid(strPDFPath, InStrRev(strPDFPath, "\") + 1, Len(strPDFPath))` and check if you are missing a reference undet Tools --> References.

Comment: put a pdf file called abc.pdf in C:\Temp , copy the code from my answer put that in the TestPDF and run.

Comment: I got the same thing